# How to hide C# class from custom IL Inspector?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, kofax

I am currently working with a piece of software known as Kofax TotalAgility or KTA for short.
This is Business Process Automation Software, which I have the "pleasure" of expanding with custom .net libraries.

I have been creating a MS Graph library to perform actions with the MS Graph API. The API works great and I am quite pleased with how it turned out.

However due to the way KTA is accessing methods in classes I have used "Data classes" (dont know if that is the right word) to use as input parameters for my methods. To be clear these methods have no functionality other than to store data for methods to use, the reason I am doing this, is because of the way it is structured in the KTA class inspector (I am assuming that KTA uses the IL Code from my library to create a list of classes and methods).

This is what I am expecting the user is shown when they are using my methods. As you can see by using classes as input parameters I get this nice hierarchical structure.
[image]

By using classes as input parameters another issue occurs which is that my "Data Classes" are show in the list of classes, which produces alot of unnecessary clutter.

Is there a way to hide these classes from the inspector? I get that it might be an internal KTA issue, which of course would mean I am not asking in the right place, and it is an internal Kofax issue.

However if there is some C# or .NET way of doing this, that would be preferable.

Comment: Make the classes `internal`?

Comment: I tried that, however since the methods are public, the input parameter classes cannot be internal as they cannot have Inconsistent accessibility.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of different terms for the data/parameter classes that you mention, such as DTO (data transfer objects), POCO (plain old C# objects), or the one that you can see in the KTA product dlls: model classes.

There is not a direct way to hide public classes from KTA.  However, when you use the KTA API via the TotalAgility.Sdk.dll, you notice that you don’t see all of the parameter classes mixed in with the list of the classes that hold the SDK functions.  The reason is just that these objects are in a separate referenced assembly: Agility.Sdk.Model.dll.   When you are configuring a .NET activity/action in KTA, it will only list the classes directly in the assembly that you specify, not referenced assemblies.

If you are using local assembly references in KTA, then this should work because you can just have your referenced assembly in the same folder as your main dll.  However if you are ILMerging into a single dll to can add it to the .NET assembly store, then this approach won’t work.

When ILMerged together, the best you can do is to have your parameter classes grouped in a namespace that helps make it clear.  What I do is have a main project with just one class that acts as a wrapper for any functions I want  to expose.  Then use ILMerge with the internalize option, which changes visibility to internal for any types not in the primary assembly.  To allow the model classes to still be public, I keep them in a specific namespace and add that namespace to the exclude list for the internalize command.  See [Internalizing Assemblies with ILMerge](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ILMergeInternalize.aspx) for more detail.

[image: Wrapper class example]

Keep in mind that anyone seeing this list is configuring a function call with your dll.  Even if they are not a skilled developer, they should at least have some competence for this type of task (hopefully).  So even if the list shows a bunch of model classes, it shouldn’t be too hard to follow instructions if you tell them which class is to be used.

Comment: Thank you, I had thought of doing this, but I did not know you could exclude specific assemblies from the internalize command.